# Export database dmp in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any possible way to export the full database .dmp file in Oracle sql developer Version 4.0.2.15?
If not and should be done by this command:

```
expdp EMP/EMP@db10g full=Y directory=D:\home dumpfile=emp.dmp logfile=expdpemp.log
```

where to use this command? and what's "@db10g" in the command? where do i get it?

Comment: `expdp` is a command line program, not a SQL statement. Just open a command prompt and run it there.

Answer (score 1):

View > DBA

Add a connection - we assume you have fairly high privs

Go to the data pump node

Right-click, use the Export Wizard

It will guide you through the steps to create and run a job which will run data pump to do your export.

This reminds me I should probably do a blog post on Data Pump support in SQLDev...